# A proposition about heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, gaussian-integral

Given this partial differential equation:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_t = u_{xx}\\ 
u(x,0)=g(x), x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The solution is:

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}}g(y)dy$$

The proposition that we have to prove is:

$$|u(x,t)| \leq \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|g(x)| ,\forall t>0$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem. What are your own ideas? And what happens if $g(x)$ has not maximum?

Comment: Hi! I didn't say it, but $g(x)$ is bounded. Yes, it's a homework problem. And the title of the exercise say that it's very easy.